# eloquent-sluggable build_from is being ignored

Tags: php, laravel

I have a class called Vara, where i have a table field called searchname. I want to do a simple setup of cviebrock eloquent sluggable but can't figure out what the issue is.

When i save my model, nothing happens, it rewrite the old value stored.

If i change in build_from to, whatthefuckisgoingon i get the same output. I have a field called handle, also tried changing the field namne to slug but same result. If i leave build_from empty i also get the same output.

If i however change save_to to something that doesn't exist i get an error. The searchname field does have a value of "Hjordnära test 33 liter", so the output is really wierd.

My guess is that build_from is being ignored, and seen as null. How do i fix this?

My Vara.php looks like this

```
use Cviebrock\EloquentSluggable\SluggableInterface;
use Cviebrock\EloquentSluggable\SluggableTrait;

class Vara extends \Eloquent implements SluggableInterface {

use SluggableTrait;

protected $sluggable = array(
    'build_from' => 'searchname',
    'save_to'    => 'handle'
);
```

In my VarorController.php

```
public function saveVara() 
{

    $id = Input::get('id');

    $vara = Vara::find(Input::get('id'));

    $vara->edited_by = Auth::user()->id;

    $vara->searchname        = Input::get('searchname');
    $vara->save();

    return $vara->getSlug();
```

**Ok a litle update, found this function in SluggableTrait.php**

```
public function sluggify($force=false)
    {
        $config = \App::make('config')->get('eloquent-sluggable::config');
        $this->sluggable = array_merge( $config, $this->sluggable );
        if ($force || $this->needsSlugging())
        {
            $source = $this->getSlugSource();
            $slug = $this->generateSlug($source);
            $slug = $this->validateSlug($slug);
            $slug = $this->makeSlugUnique($slug);
            $this->setSlug($slug);
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

so if i add $vara->sluggify(true); to my controller the slug is being saved, so now the questions is why it does not sluggify automaticly on $vara->save();

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, it's an issue of validation because you're using [Ardent](https://github.com/laravelbook/ardent):

> Ardent is a package that "provides **self-validating** smart models for Laravel Framework 4's Eloquent ORM"

Check your rules and use `if` statement:

```
if(! $vara->save()) // if model is invalid
    dd($vara->errors());
```

If you don't need to check validation , you may use

```
$vara->forceSave();
```

To integrate Eloquent sluggable with Ardent, take a look at this [link](https://github.com/cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable/blob/master/README-Ardent.md)